# Fill pdf forms with play on linux?

Tags: 18.04

My os is Ubuntu 18.04.2. 
If i install play on linux that come with adobe reader dc it will have the latest version for adobe? 
I want to fill pdf forms for taxes and needs the latest version from adobe reader.